# rto create an instance of class ByteBuffer but getting error saying "cannot instantiate type ByteBuffer

Tags: java

when i have the following line of code to creat a instance of ByteBuffer
I get a error saying "cannot instantiate type ByteBuffer"
ByteBuffer get=new ByteBuffer();

program
static int g=0;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    URL website = new URL("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/1coinUSD.csv.gz");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    ERROR ON LINE BELOW
    ByteBuffer get=new ByteBuffer();

    rbc.read(get);
    ted=get.array();

    readInFile(first);
    readInFile(second);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an abstract class, ByteBuffer can't be instantiated directly, but you can use the [`allocate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate%28int%29) or [`allocateDirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) factory methods:

To choose whether you need a direct buffer, read the class-level Javadoc:

> A byte buffer is either direct or non-direct. Given a direct byte buffer, the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it. That is, it will attempt to avoid copying the buffer's content to (or from) an intermediate buffer before (or after) each invocation of one of the underlying operating system's native I/O operations.
>
> A direct byte buffer may be created by invoking the `allocateDirect` factory method of this class. The buffers returned by this method typically have somewhat higher allocation and deallocation costs than non-direct buffers. The contents of direct buffers may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap, and so their impact upon the memory footprint of an application might not be obvious. It is therefore recommended that direct buffers be allocated primarily for large, long-lived buffers that are subject to the underlying system's native I/O operations. In general it is best to allocate direct buffers only when they yield a measureable gain in program performance.

You may also consider [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html), for a ByteBuffer instance corresponding to a *memory-mapped region of a file*.

Comment: or [`allocate(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate-int-), which might be cheaper to do depending on the use case.

Comment: @Mark Thanks! Oversight fixed.

Answer (score 1):

ByteBuffer is an abstract class. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html